# removing {^D ctrl+d } junk from a file using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using a shell & TCL script to login to a switch and get the output of certain commands and in some places I can see `^D` coming up. I tried to use the `dos2unix` utility but still it didn't go away.

```
Eth1/37       NOM:               xcvrAbsen routed    auto    auto    --
^DEth1/38       NOM:               xcvrAbsen routed    auto    auto    --
Eth1/39       NOM:               xcvrAbsen routed    auto    auto    --

Eth101/1/45   eth    1000    NOM:NO_PATCHING CABLE
^DEth101/1/46   eth    1000    NOM:NO_PATCHING CABLE
Eth101/1/47   eth    1000    NOM:NO_PATCHING CABLE
```

How can this be eliminated, are there any standard tools like `dos2unix` which can get rid of such data?

What I'm trying to do is to compare two files which are from the same switch and the same command and the same output, but due to these `^D`, Vimdiff shows it as different lines.

How to get this eliminated?

Command I'm using is something like this:

```
$cdir/ciscocmd -Y -u $operator -p $password -s $password -t $switch -r rfc_sa_commands | sed 's/^^D//' > $switch.$NOW
```

Answer (score 3):

`dos2unix` removes carriage returns, no other control characters.

The tool to remove all occurrences of an arbitrary character is called `tr`.

```
tr -d '\004' <inputfile >outputfile
```

This assumes you have literal ctrl-D characters, not sequences of caret `^` and `D`. The `tr` utility cannot remove a specific sequence; it just processes individual characters. To remove a sequence, you'd need

```
sed 's/\^D//g' inputfile >outputfile
```

where the backslash is required because the caret alone has a special meaning in regular expressions (it matches beginning of line). Doubling it does not escape it; `^^` probably still just matches beginning of line, though it's not really well-defined, and could introduce apparently random behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the special character is visible as '^D', it may be NOT catchable like this.

Interesting readings, are:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_groups
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character

I think a way to do it would be:

```
<your command>|sed -e 's/\x04//g'
```

Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Hex escapes may work in some versions of `sed`, but are not standard or portable.

Comment: it is some how still coming up `interface port-channel1                                           |  interface port-channel1
 _ ^D^D^D^D^D^D^D_  description N` , currently i'm using something like this   **` | sed 's/^^D//' | sed -e 's/\x04//g' | sed -e 's/\0D//g' > $file
`** , Also just to let you know why i want this to be removed is coz i'm using a vimdiff which catches these extra as a difference in 2 files which are actually same data but has EOT's an CR's in different places for no reason .